# SQL Exception when using ExecuteScalar in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am working on a login page for an asp.net application. I'm making my own login and everything is working so far: I get a connection, the query is asking to return Count from the table where the username and password match the username password in the table.

The problem occurs here:

```
intResult = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
```

I get the error: `Invalid Column name "MemberLogin" "MemberPassword"`

Here is the pertinent code:

```
 Dim strSQLQuery As String
        strSQLQuery = "SELECT Count(*) WHERE [MemberLogin] = @MemberLogin And [MemberPassword] = @MemberPassword"
        Dim intResult As Integer = 0

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQLQuery, sqlConnection)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberLogin", txtUsername.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberPassword", txtPassword.Text)
        sqlConnection.Open()

        intResult = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)

        If intResult > 0 Then
            Return True
        End If

        sqlConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing your `FROM` clause

```
SELECT Count(*)
```

**FROM yourTable** needs to go here

```
WHERE [MemberLogin] = @MemberLogin
   And [MemberPassword] = @MemberPassword
```